# Unable to send 128 Bytes data from Javacard but can send 127 Bytes as a response to APDU command when using sendBytesLong()

Tags: applet, javacard, apdu

While sending data from javacard in the form APDU commands using the apdu.sendBytesLong() Function, I am able to send 127 bytes data as response but 128 bytes data give error code 6f00(SW_UNKNOWN).
Why is this happening and can anybody suggest the way around without splitting the data into two apdu commands.

```
le = apdu.setOutgoing();
            if(le != 128)
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
apdu.setOutgoingLength((byte)le);
apdu.sendBytesLong(mod_PkAIKR,(short)0, le);
```

where mod_PkAIKR is an byte array of 128 bytes.

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect us to find out without revealing the relevant parts of your code? And by relevant I mean the part of the Java Card code where you process the APDU and the APDU trace of your communication with the card.

Comment: @MichaelRoland There is no need of code but still I have added.

Comment: Sure you need to post code (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you expect us to find out why your *code* does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`apdu.setOutgoingLength((byte)le);`
to
`apdu.setOutgoingLength(le);`

1. The parameter type of api `apdu.setOutgoing()` is short, it didn't needs type convert.
2. If you convert *le* to type *byte*, the parameter value will be a nagative. the value of `(byte) 128` is `-128`.